# translation of 귀족으로서 좀 더 긍지 높은 자세를 갖추세요

Tags: translation

I'm a bit unsure about this sentence: 
"귀족으로서 좀 더 긍지 높은 자세를 갖추세요!"

So the situation before that is that someone make a mistake, and thus she was scolded like that. I translate it as "as a noble, please behave with more pride!" but somehow i feel it was a bit weird...

Answer (score 2):

귀족으로서 좀 더 긍지 높은 자세를 갖추세요!

From [Papago](https://papago.naver.com/?sk=ko&tk=en&st=%EA%B7%80%EC%A1%B1%EC%9C%BC%EB%A1%9C%EC%84%9C%20%EC%A2%80%20%EB%8D%94%20%EA%B8%8D%EC%A7%80%20%EB%86%92%EC%9D%80%20%EC%9E%90%EC%84%B8%EB%A5%BC%20%EA%B0%96%EC%B6%94%EC%84%B8%EC%9A%94):

> Be more proud of yourself as a nobleman.

Let's break down the sentence based on page linked above:

귀족으로서 -> 귀족 + 으로서
귀족 = nobleman
으로서 = ["as" in the sense of "as a teacher](https://wiseinit.com/%EC%9C%BC%EB%A1%9C%EC%8D%A8-%EC%9C%BC%EB%A1%9C%EC%84%9C-korean-grammar-vs-grammar-7/)
An example sentence from the linked page above:

> 선생님으로서 네가 잘못하는 것을 보고만 있을 수는 없다.
>   As a teacher, I cannot just see you
>   doing wrong.

So the above sentence would be something like

> As a nobleman(woman)....

좀 더 => a bit more

긍지  => pride
높은 => from 높다 => high
자세 => attitude
갖추세요 => from 갖추다+(으)세요 => 갖추다 => prepare, possess

Based on the context given the question itself, I think a close translation of this sentence could be

> As a nobleman, show a bit more pride.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when a person made a mistake, then we can say

1) 그게 뭐냐 ? What is it ?

2) 똑바로 해라 정신 안 차릴래 ? Please do it correctly. Be careful

3) 작은 거에 너무 신경 쓰지마 Ignore trivial things

That is, with respect to several situations we have various
corresponds.

Further, sometimes a noble can make a trivial mistake. Surely, it is
usual that usual guy makes such mistakes. But a noble has several
safety so that it is unusual that he makes such mistake. Hence when
usual guy makes such mistake, we comment to prohibit a recurrence
but for a noble guy, we comment about his forthcoming behaving